# Serve mp4 file through coldfusion and play with jwplayer

Tags: ios, coldfusion, jwplayer, mp4

I have an web application in coldfusion which record videos and serve videos to user.

The video is working fine on android and desktop browsers but it is giving me error "Error loading media: File could not be played" in IOS.

Here is my JWPlayer code which is currently working.

```
jwplayer("element").setup({
  file: "/video.cfm?token=4514_129_9B2F727D-5056-A85D-6EBE3E48FC2AB9C6",
  image: "path/to/image",
  width: 450,
  height: 360,
  type: "mp4",
  logo: {
     file: 'path/to/logo',
     link: 'example.com',
     hide : true
  }
});
```

Here is my video.cfm to server mp4 after verification.

```
<cfset videoFile = 'path\to\file'>
<cfset fileInfo = GetFileInfo(videoFile)>
<cfset length = fileInfo.size>
<cfset start = 0>
<cfset end = fileInfo.size - 1>
<cfheader name="Content-type" value="video/mp4">
<cfheader name="Accept-Ranges" value="0-#length#">
<cfheader name="Content-Range" value="bytes #start#-#end#/#fileInfo.size#">
<cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#length#">
<cfcontent file="#videoFile#" type="video/mp4">
```

I have tried some solution by adding some header. But that doesn't work. Can anyone help me to sort out the problem.

Comment: If you give us access to the site (at least the front end), we can probably help diagnose it. I've delivered projects with CF, video, and jwplayer together.

Comment: Away from your own app, are the file(s) playable at all in your iOS device? I mean just be sure the file data itself is acceptable for iOS playback. Save one file from server to storage & try to play in some media player app... what happens? Tested same file on a different (specs/power) iOS device?

Comment: @VC.One. I have added different demo on  https://jwplayer-techy.fwd.wf/. There is only one file which is working on IOS is through hlshtml: true. Have you have idea that how can i use this parameter to run mp4 from file?

Comment: @Jules. Here is the test example url using my code https://jwplayer-techy.fwd.wf/. Please see

Comment: One thing I see right away is that the content-type of the CFM/MP4 is coming through as "video/mp4;charset=UTF-8", whereas the straight served MP4 is simply "video/mp4".

Comment: @Jules. Thanks for your response. can you please let me know that how can i fix the content-type

Comment: @AbdulRauf also I noticed your **mp4** is really an **f4v** file with extension just changed to `.mp4` I think that's what stopping iOS accepting it.

Comment: @VC.One. that could be an issue. Let me check it also. :)

Comment: @VC.One. There is one behavior, i have noted. If you see last two example on jwplayer-techy.fwd.wf. You will notice, one is coming from //vr.jwplayer.com/content/AgqYcfAT/AgqYcfAT-8yQ1cYbs.mp4 is working perfectly in IOS. I have download it and run it locally and same file doesn't work in IOS. I think i need to change something in IIS that how it is handling it. If you have any suggestion. Please let me know.

Comment: First make sure you're really serving a proper MP4 per @VC.One.

Comment: @Jules. Yes, i am using hdfvr for recording and wowza trans coder API to convert the file to mp4. The issue is that video.cfm is not sending the content Partially.

Comment: @AbdulRauf I don't have access to an iOS device to check. Also I'm not much a server guy so can't advise about IIS. All I know is your bytes were f4v. Also I think Wowza is involved(?), if yes then see if you can adjust Wowza or IIS output settings to give mp4.

Comment: @VC.One. Thanks. I have figured it out. I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to resolve my problem. iOS uses a partial content header to run videos. Thanks to rickward for this lovely solution: [Media Delivery to iPhones and iPads](http://rickawd.tumblr.com/post/15343511500/media-delivery-to-iphones-and-ipads). I have made some little changes and it started working for me.

Here is the final video.cfm file.

```
<cfset videoPath = 'path\to\mp4\file'>
<cfif FileExists(videoPath)>
    <cfset fileInfoVar = GetFileInfo(videoPath)>
    <cfheader name="Last-Modified" value="#fileInfoVar.Lastmodified#">
    <cfheader name="ETag" value="#hash(videoPath, 'MD5')#">
    <cfheader name="Content-Location" value="http://example.com/video.cfm">

    <cfif structKeyExists(GetHttpRequestData().headers, 'Range')>
        <cfset rangeDownload(videoPath)>
    <cfelse>
        <cffile action="readbinary" file="#videoPath#" variable="theData">
        <cfscript>
            context = getPageContext();
            context.setFlushOutput(false);
            response = context.getResponse().getResponse();
            response.setContentType("video/mp4");
            response.setContentLength(arrayLen(theData));

            out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(theData);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        </cfscript>
    </cfif>
</cfif>

<cffunction name="rangeDownload" returnType="void" output="yes">
    <cfargument name="file" type="string" required="true" hint="path to file">

    <cfset var l = {}>
    <cfset l.request = GetHttpRequestData()>

    <cffile action="readbinary" file="#ARGUMENTS.file#" variable="l.theData">

    <cfset l.size = arrayLen(l.theData)>
    <cfset l.length = l.size>
    <cfset l.start  = 0>
    <cfset l.end = l.size - 1>

    <!--- Now that we've gotten so far without errors we send the accept range header
    /* At the moment we only support single ranges.
     * Multiple ranges requires some more work to ensure it works correctly
     * and comply with the spesifications: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2
     *
     * Multirange support annouces itself with:
     * header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
     *
     * Multirange content must be sent with multipart/byteranges mediatype,
     * (mediatype = mimetype)
     * as well as a boundry header to indicate the various chunks of data.
     */
    --->
    <cfheader name="Accept-Ranges" value="0-#l.length#">
    <!---<cfheader name="Accept-Ranges" value="bytes"> --->
    <!---
      multipart/byteranges
      http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2 --->
    <cfif structKeyExists(l.request.headers, 'Range')>

        <cfset l.c_start = l.start>
        <cfset l.c_end = l.end>

        <!--- Extract the range string --->
        <cfset l.range = ListGetAt(l.request.headers.range, 2, '=')>
        <!--- Make sure the client hasn't sent us a multibyte range --->
        <cflog file="rangeDownload" text="#l.range#" />
        <cfif l.range contains ','>
            <!--- (?) Should this be issued here, or should the first
             range be used? Or should the header be ignored and
             we output the whole content?
            --->
            <cfheader statusCode = "416" statusText = "Requested Range Not Satisfiable">
            <cfheader name="Content-Range" value="bytes #l.start#-#l.end#/#l.size#">
            <!--- (?) Echo some info to the client? --->
            <cfabort>
        </cfif>
        <!--- If the range starts with an '-' we start from the beginning
            If not, we forward the file pointer
            And make sure to get the end byte if specified --->
        <cfif Left(l.range, 1) eq '-'>
        <!--- The n-number of the last bytes is requested --->
            <cfset l.c_start = l.size - Mid(l.range, 2, Len(l.range))>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset l.rangeArray = ListToArray(l.range, '-')>
            <cfset l.c_start = l.rangeArray[1]>
            <cfif ArrayLen(l.rangeArray) eq 2 and val(l.rangeArray[2]) gt 0>
                <cfset l.c_end = l.rangeArray[2]>
            <cfelse>
                <cfset l.c_end = l.size>
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
        <!---
        /* Check the range and make sure it's treated according to the specs.
         * http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
         */
        // End bytes can not be larger than l.end. --->
        <cfif l.c_end gt l.end>
            <cfset l.c_end = l.end>
        </cfif>

        <!--- Validate the requested range and return an error if it's not correct. --->
        <cfif l.c_start gt l.c_end || l.c_start gt (l.size - 1) || l.c_end gte l.size>
            <cfheader statusCode = "416" statusText = "Requested Range Not Satisfiable">
            <cfheader name="Content-Range" value="bytes #l.start#-#l.end#/#l.size#">
            <!--- (?) Echo some info to the client? --->
            <cfabort>
        </cfif>

        <cfset l.start = l.c_start>
        <cfset l.end = l.c_end>
        <cfset l.length = l.end - l.start + 1><!--- Calculate new content length --->


        <cfscript>
            context = getPageContext();
            context.setFlushOutput(false);
            response = context.getResponse().getResponse();
            response.setContentType("video/mp4");
            response.setContentLength(l.length);
        </cfscript>
        <cfheader statusCode = "206" statusText = "Partial Content">

    </cfif>

    <!--- Notify the client the byte range we'll be outputting --->
    <cfheader name="Content-Range" value="bytes #l.start#-#l.end#/#l.size#">
    <cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#l.length#">

    <cfscript>
        // Start buffered download
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        // write the portion requested
        out.write(l.theData, javacast('int', l.start), javacast('int', l.length));
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Small suggestion, you could probably simplify that first `<cfelse>` and just use `<cfcontent>`. Also, do not forget to `var/local` scope all of the variables in the function, including `context, response, out`, etcetera.

Comment: @Leigh. Thanks for your suggestion. I will surly change it according to your suggestions. :)